# Real-Time Computaion! Processing Speed Problem!

Tags: raspbian-wheezy, sensor, memory, real-time, signal

I am pretty new to the c++ and raspberry pi.

I am trying to run a real time sensor motor control  with the help of Raspberry pi, using cpp. I am sniffing the sensor data through Ethernet and sending control signal to motor through usb. (Using lpcap libraries).

I just wanted to run this program on my RPi. I have installed "Raspbian Wheezy minimal distribution" for this purpose. My sensor processing speed is better, but still having latency in signal sniffing and execution. On ubuntu workstation I found that the total process is using only 13 mb OF MEMORY. I don't understand why still my signal processing speed is low on RPi, compared to that of workstation!! Is it possible to increase the processing speed, in some other manner?

Comment: Try using RiscOS for real time processing instead of Event Driven Operating system like Debian.

Comment: The NIC on the Pi is connected via USB. That might cause some additional latency. Have you tried running `top` on the Pi, to see memory/cpu usage?

Comment: Why do you use ethernet also? I2C and UART works much better since its buid into the hardware.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can overclock the pi to increase it's processing speed by running

`sudo raspi-config`

and selecting the **overclock** option, if this helps.

I would also add that the higher you overclock the processor, the more unstable it may become. try incrementing overclock speeds slowly, and see what impact it has on your process.